# Overwrite existing data in tabs using macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a found a macro online that read in "dat" file or "text" file and put them in the open excel, creates a tab for every single file that is in the folder designated using the macro below. Now the issue is that I have to keep in re-importing new data in the same excel because data is changing or i just have to re read that file in again.

So this macro always creates a new tab if the name already exist. I need it to overwrite the data and not recreate a new tab. I have other tab that are referencing the imported data tabs. so I am not sure how to do that.

```
Sub loadMacro()
'UpdatebyExtendoffice6/7/2016
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xToBook As Workbook
Dim xStrPath As String
Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
Dim xFile As String
Dim xFiles As New Collection
Dim I As Long

Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
xFileDialog.Title = "C:\Users\"
If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
    xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
End If
If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
If Right(xStrPath, 1) <> "\" Then xStrPath = xStrPath & "\"
xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "*.dat")
If xFile = "" Then
    MsgBox "No files found", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
    Exit Sub
End If
Do While xFile <> ""
    xFiles.Add xFile, xFile
    xFile = Dir()
Loop
Set xToBook = ThisWorkbook
If xFiles.Count > 0 Then
    For I = 1 To xFiles.Count
        Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(xStrPath & xFiles.Item(I))
        xWb.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=xToBook.Sheets(xToBook.Sheets.Count)
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.Name = xWb.Name
        On Error GoTo 0
        xWb.Close False
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `xWb.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=xToBook.Sheets(xToBook.Sheets.Count)` is what makes your new tab

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```vb
xWb.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=xToBook.Sheets(xToBook.Sheets.Count)
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Name = xWb.Name
On Error GoTo 0
```

with

```vb
On Error Resume Next
xToBook.Worksheets(xWb.name).Cells.Clear
With xWb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
    xToBook.Worksheets(xWb.name).Cells(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
End With
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Hey Chris, thank you for taking time to help me. So I updated my macro as you suggested. Although it is not recreating new tabs which is great. however it is not overwriting my old data with the new data, which is my primary goal. Thank you again for your help.